# Enum.TryParse Run-time exception

Tags: c#, enums

we've found an exception in our logs and its unclear to us how this code could be valid, can someone please explain why this codesnippet results in an Run-time exception instead of being a Compile-time error?

```
    string variant = "Variant";
    int result;
    Enum.TryParse(variant, out result);
```

Link to dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWhkz3

Thanks in advance,

Marcel!

Comment: you are using out result which is an int type. whilst enum.tryparse expect to be outputted as an Enum. so use var result; instead

Comment: It's relatively recent that it's been possible to constrain generic types to be of an enum type, and apparently that's not been applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [Enum.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-enum-tryparse-1(system-string-0@)) in .Net you can see the method signature:

```
public static bool TryParse<TEnum> (string value, out TEnum result) where TEnum : struct;
```

I.e. it is only constrained to struct types, and int fulfills that requirement. Documentation also contains

> ArgumentException
>
> TEnum is not an enumeration type.

So it is working as intended.

The Enum constraint was [added in c# 7.3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/), but it does not look like Enum.TryParse is making use of it. C# and the compiler have improved over the years, and this code would likely not compile if `TryParse` was written today. But backward compatibility is important, so I kind of understand if they do not change existing behavior without a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare which enumType result is. you cannot use result as type int as an out variable on Enum.TryParse

```
public enum ExampleEnum
{
    Variant
}
public class Program
{


        public static void Main()
        {
            string variant = "Variant";
            ExampleEnum result;
            Enum.TryParse(variant, out result);
        }

}
```